# Django How to Calculate DateTimeField?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, model

How can I calculate DateTimeFields?

I want the user to put the loan StartDate and LoanEndDate and the months paid and left gets automatically calculated like what I did with the money instance

how to make a monthly payment table from the start and end date ??

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=5)
    paid = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    remaining = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)

    LoanStartDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    LoanEndDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    monthspaid = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    monthsleft = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def balance_reciever(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        amount = instance.amount
        paid = instance.paid
        remaining = amount - paid
        instance.remaining = remaining
```

Comment: Do you want to payment table based on agent? I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying ❤, finally someone I can ask .. the company manager adds agents that took the loan from him and he wants to make a management system for that

Comment: so I'm having a problem in calculating dates when the company manager puts the loan start and end date it should be saved on the database as months and each month he can make it paid or not + the moths paid and months left without paing gets calculated

Comment: i can't find any explaination on how to do that anywhere and don't even know what is that called to search .. thx again <3